# Mysql. IF в WHERE

Tags: база-данных, запрос, mysql

Можно ли средствами MYSQL сделать такую логику в WHERE:

```
выбрать из таблицы ТАБЛИЦА где ПОЛЕ_1 = 1 и если ( ПОЛЕ_2 = YES , ТО ПОЛЕ_3!=0)
```

Решил)
Как я описал выше так я и написал:

```
$where = "`pav_type`='PAVILION' AND IF(`pav_combined` = 'YES',`pav_extra_pav_num`!=0,`pav_extra_pav_num`=0)";
```

Comment: Т.е. ответ есть. Нужно придумать для него вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

эээ, ну и что сложного

```
`pav_type`='PAVILION' AND ((`pav_combined` = 'YES' AND `pav_extra_pav_num`!=0) OR ( `pav_combined` != 'YES' AND `pav_extra_pav_num`=0))";
```